# how to copy image from filepiker to app folder windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

this is the code of file picker
i need to copy the image that user open it to app folder.
any one can help me please

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value != Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.Snapped ||
             Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.TryUnsnap() == true)
        {
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            openPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

            // Filter to include a sample subset of file types.
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
```

// Open the file picker.

```
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            // file is null if user cancels the file picker.
            if (file != null)
            {
                // Open a stream for the selected file.
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                    await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
```

// Set the image source to the selected bitmap.`

```
                Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage =
                    new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

                bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                img.Source = bitmapImage;
                this.DataContext = file;


            }
        }

    }
```

thanks

Comment: So what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StorageFile.CopyAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227190.aspx), that is, file.CopyAsync. The first argument is the destination StorageFolder, e.g. Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder if you wanted to copy to appdata; otherwise you'd need to create a folder or get one from a picker separately.

You might, for example, have the user choose a default folder with the file picker (configured for folders). Just be sure to save that StorageFolder in the `[Windows.Storage.AccessCache][2]` to preserve programmatic access for future use.